# ImportError: cannot import name 'image_to_string' from 'pytesseract' (unknown location)

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I installed tesseract via homebrew and I'm using a virtual environment called Virtualenv in VS Code.

The error when running the code(Python) is this:

ImportError: cannot import name 'image_to_string' from 'pytesseract' (unknown location)

Any ideas that can help me?

follow the python code below.

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from PIL import Image
import PIL
import pytesseract

print(image_to_string(Image.open('base-image/ocr.png')))
```

Comment: Maybe installing via `pip install tesseract` might solve  the issue. Since I'm using `pytesseract` via `pip`

Comment: I already tried this way and dont work it. My  OS is Mac OS Big Sur.